# Why a SWF button works in IE and Firefox but not in Google Chrome?

Tags: html, swfobject

I have this piece of code in my contact us page :

```
     <button name="Submit" id="Submit" type="submit" style=" border-style: none; border-width: 0; background-color:transparent" >
<object data="swf/sending.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="190" height="46" form="msg">
<param name="movie" value ="swf/sending.swf" />
<param name="quality" value="High">
<param name="wmode" value="transparent">
<embed src="swf/sending.swf" width="190" height="46" quality="High" 
wmode="transparent">
</object>           
</button>
```

When I go to the page address and I try to send a message by clicking the button, it runs well and sends message to my email address if I use IE or Firefox but in Google Chrome I don't receive any message. I don't know what the problem is. If anybody help< I will appreciate so much.
And this is the form code in this page:

```
<form method="post" action="email.php">
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: isn't there some code missing? seems like a normal button to me, instead of a swf button...

Answer (score 0):

```
<button name="Submit" id="Submit" type="submit" style=" border-style: none; border-width: 0; background-color:transparent" >
```

is different than

```
<input name="Submit" id="Submit" type="submit" style=" border-style: none; border-width: 0; background-color:transparent" />
```

By the way, you should close the `button` tag:

```
<button name="Submit" id="Submit" type="submit" style=" border-style: none; border-width: 0; background-color:transparent" >Something</button>
```

or

```
 <button name="Submit" id="Submit" type="submit" style=" border-style: none; border-width: 0; background-color:transparent" >&nbsp;</button>
```